# Missing or moved control panels after migrating from Plone 4.3 to 5.1

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

After migrating a 4.3.18 instance to 5.1.5, the "Date and Time" control panel is missing in the Site Setup page and the following control panels are moved to a "Plone Configuration" category from their original category (as can be seen from a vanilla installation) :

- Language (from General to Plone configuration) - it has a different icon too
- Mail (from General to Plone configuration)
- Discussion (from General to Plone configuration)
- Image Handling (from Content to Plone configuration)
- HTML Filtering (from Security to Plone configuration)

I'm mainly disturbed by the absent "Date and Time" control panel. It is worth mentioning that on the Site Setup page just after the migration, there were warnings advertising unset preferences in "Date and Time" and "Mail" control panels - while those preferences were set in the original 4.3 site!

Besides, during the "normal" (and succesful) migration (I mean before the optional step to convert contents to Dexterity), I got the following line repeated regularly :

Step collective.z3cform.datetimewidget has an invalid import handler

Finally, this does not seem to be related to Dexterity migration since this is true even if I don't install Dexterity and keep ArcheTypes content types.

What can I do to fix this?

As a side note, do I have to care about those control panels that have been moved around in the Configuration page? Is this the sign of something going wrong elsewhere?

Comment: Confirming missing entry in overview-controlpanel for date'n'time after upgrading a vanilla Plone-4.3.19-site to version 5.1.2 or 5.1.5. Couldn't find a bug-report.You might want to open one on github.com/plone/products.cmfplone/issues

Comment: The "invalid import handler" might be neglectable, if not causing troubles, but is still worthwhile to check, if there's a bug-report already, or needs to be created. Encountred this err-msg while testing repeatedly deriving of other packages than collective.z3cform.datetimewidget

Comment: The panels were moved around intentionally.

Comment: Moved to https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/2824

Comment: Yes, reported it Tuesday. @IdaEbkes : how is the link for you? Does it have the @@historyview thingie?

Comment: You refer to the other question #55433144 probably? :-) Anyway, yes @@historyview is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirming described bug. You need to add a `controlpanel.xml`in one of your self-made add-on's profile-folder with these lines:

```
<object name="portal_controlpanel" meta_type="Plone Control Panel Tool"
  i18n:domain="plone" xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n">
 <configlet title="Date and Time" action_id="DateAndTime" appId="DateAndTime"
    category="plone-general" condition_expr=""
    icon_expr="string:$portal_url/event_icon.png"
    url_expr="string:${portal_url}/@@dateandtime-controlpanel" visible="True"
    i18n:attributes="title">
  <permission>Plone Site Setup: Site</permission>
 </configlet>
</object>
```

Tried adding it through the webinterface via `[SITE_URL]/portal_controlpanel/manage_editActionsForm`, but clicking 'add' results in a error-silenting redirection (404).

Comment: Same result here TTW. Unfortunately we don't have any self-made add-on and don't know how to make one. I'll keep an eye on the Github issue. Thank you @ida, you made my day yesterday on the other issue.

Comment: That's great! You can make an add-on with `pip install adi.devgen` and then do `devgen addProfile your.addon`.